# Cannot Execute Blockchain Contract on Azure Deployed by Visual Studio

Tags: azure, visual-studio-2015, blockchain, ethereum, solidity

I'm following "Solidity in Visual Studio" video in the Microsoft Virtual Academy tutorial on blockchain at https://mva.microsoft.com/en-us/training-courses/microsoft-blockchain-as-a-service-17104?l=aZrQbG3SD_3206218965.  In that video, a sample program provided is deployed to a Strato Blockchain Individual Instance on Azure.

```
contract SimpleStorage {
    uint storedData;
    function set(uint x) {
        storedData = x;
    }
    function get() returns (uint retVal) {
        return storedData;
    }
}
```

Before the contract is deployed, a local instance of bloc has to be running.

When I try the same example, the smart contract gets deployed and starts up fine and I'm able to execute the getter.  But when I try the setter, bloc crashes on my laptop.  Here is the bloc output:

```
args: {}
method: set
helo

address found

{ encSeed:
    {encStr: 'U2FsdGVkX1+rnMeKw5ruG3Nm7wo1HZB79+6IOxxTYIsWkjEK+oi8aRcgu8qZUHGk8Dzl0
W1flMrRNHoBI+vlc6B6Y80ZJFunr/74Sm33J1
2iLstqKChU25WwwrYgC4FT5M7+HpnCbOAAI73SHElnnQ==',
        iv: '81b01f2c746a150d2d90dd4e7e8fcd3b',
        salt: 'ab9cc78ac39aee1b' },
  encHdRootPriv:
   {     encStr: 'U2FsdGVkX1+ZVfqWpJulET/0hMdcOuP1hZiiHmdtIS1SQRec1MWjrDH74rQLwLnI6Nb9+/
QjKgVrukvx6X0qD9gdBCVmqwhTXyBoehGBO1  
8BiT56YhDjxDrND58VGRtnSJ3DckHV8hWdWZ/0hXUfFTX3R89fOMYJkZ1kIlwvVks=',
        iv: 'd68c7af4572a1010231b97fd1bec30d1',
        salt: '9955fa96a49ba511' },
  hdIndex: 1,
  encPrivKeys:
   { fa42ead356d36889cad001b3f2a1dcc76ac32335:
      {     key: 'U2FsdGVkX1/FHsekWKPETUIsd1rSqiir4rCjznpOzDowl6PNq+ZEjUxtCwWmIwM/EiGE2L7NbJ    G2vIQHBZbFSg==',
        iv: '24fe08e7154b8ae772dd6428add029b8',
        salt: 'c51ec7a458a3c44d' } },
  addresses: [ 'fa42ead356d36889cad001b3f2a1dcc76ac32335' ],
  keyHash: '740225dd2e0bbd99aaba45f50052df1096d3b0787546d93e69533c234c1379fbd6573a    b9a55c0d5467244fe1f0c89d1ee99d51701702642b6b831d682f898145',
  salt:
   { words: [ 1010446473, -1142563966, -1306880551, -740663341 ],
     sigBytes: 16 } }

trying to invoke contract

args: {}
```

Can anyone help me figure out why bloc is failing?  I'm using Visual Studio 2015 with the Solidity extension and bloc version 1.2.2 on Windows 7.

Answer (score 0):

This issue is caused because the Solidity extension for VS, by default will use http://strato-dev4.blockapps.net as the Strato endpoint (blockchain backend).  This server was taken offline.  You can create your own instance of Strato (https://azuremarketplace.microsoft.com/en-us/marketplace/apps/blockapps.strato-blockchain-lts-vm?tab=Overview).  You can then target it by updated your local bloc instance config (config.yaml) to point to this new endpoint.